# Decorators and dependency injection in symfony2

Tags: php, oop, symfony, dependency-injection

For example, I have some interface:

```
interface ISmsRepository {
    public function send(SmsMessage $sms);
}
```

And I have implementation of this class:

```
class SmsRepository implements ISmsRepository{/**some implementation*/}
```

And now I want to realize decorator for SmsRepository class:

```
class QueueSmsRepository implements ISmsRepository{
    /**
     * @var ISmsRepository
     */
    private $smsRepository;

    public function __construct(ISmsRepository $repository) {
        $this->smsRepository = $repository;
    }

    public function send(SmsMessage $sms) {
        //some addable actions
        $this->smsRepository->send($sms);
    }
}
```

I can more than one of decorators. How can i describe it in config? I tried to do like:

```
<service id="manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.sms_repository"
             class="Manyrus\SmsBundle\Lib\Decorators\QueueSmsRepository">
        <argument type="service" id="manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.sms_repository"/>
</service>
```

But i have a error:

> Circular reference detected for service "manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.sms_repository", path: "manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.sms_repository -> manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.sms_repository".

I don't know, what to do. Now, I see only one exit from this situation - create service, that will decorate my SmsRepository. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You are injecting the service on it self. You should inject another sms service to decorate them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [decorating-services](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#decorating-services) and no need to use compiler pass.

```
<service id="manyrus_decorated"
         class="Manyrus\SmsBundle\Lib\SmsRepository">
    <argument />
</service>

<service id="manyrus_decorator" class="Manyrus\SmsBundle\Lib\Decorators\QueueSmsRepository" decorates="manyrus_decorated" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="manyrus_decorator.inner" />
</service>
```

Then you still work with the orginal service name:

```
manyrus_decorated
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question answered when is it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually alter some definitions. You can do it in your extension file directly but I would suggest you to use a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html) if you want other bundles to be able to add a decorator:

```
// ../DependencyInjection/Compiler/DecorateSmsRepository.php    

namespace Manyrus\SmsBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class DecorateSmsRepository implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $repositoryId = 'manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.sms_repository';

        if (!$container->hasDefinition($repositoryId)) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->getDefinition($repositoryId);

        // Retrieve the ids of the services tagged with "manyrus.sms_bundle.sms_repository.decorator".
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds(
            'manyrus.sms_bundle.sms_repository.decorator'
        );

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $attributes) {
            // Replace the first argument passed to the constructor by the decorator.
            $definition->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($id));

            // Chain the decorator mechanism.
            $definition = $container->getDefinition($id);
            $repositoryId = $id;
        }

        // Set an alias on the last decorator (this will be the service you want to use).
        $container->setAlias(
            'manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.decorated_sms_repository',
            new Alias($repositoryId, false)
        );
    }
}
```

The definition of your services should be:

```
<service id="manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.sms_repository"
         class="Manyrus\SmsBundle\Lib\SmsRepository">
    <argument />
</service>

<service id="manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.sms_repository.decorator.queue"
         class="Manyrus\SmsBundle\Lib\Decorators\QueueSmsRepository">
    <argument />
    <tag name="manyrus.sms_bundle.sms_repository.decorator" />
</service>
```

Last thing to do is to register your compiler pass in your bundle file:

```
// ../ManyrusSmsBundle.php

namespace Manyrus\SmsBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Manyrus\SmsBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DecorateSmsRepository;

class DaOAuthClientBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new DecorateSmsRepository());
    }
}
```

Then you can work with the service `manyrus.sms_bundle.decorated.epochta.decorated_sms_repository`.